# Jasper report mongodb connection won't close

Tags: mongodb, jasperserver

I have a jasper report *.jrxml file that had a list which has Dataset Run with connection to Mongo DB database.

[image: my list]

The $F(ConnectionString) is a value for Mongo DB connection string from an Sql database.

My issue is that whenever user run these reports in the server, it opens so many connection from the server to Mongo DB and seemed that Jasper never closes them after opening. This, at some point causes the server to hang/not responsive.

Here is my netstat -no | find "27017" result:
[image: netstat result]

My question is: how can we make sure that jasper closes connection to Mongo DB everytime it successffully connected and retrieves data from Mongo DB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `seemed that Jasper never closes them after opening` - What is Jasper? Are you talking about Jaspersoft Studio? Or some custom application? JRS?

Comment: yes, Jasper Server